# Use a cell as a 'template' for conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

Maybe I'm being stupid and missing a trick, but I am looking to create an example excel file for conditional formatting.

I am happy with conditional format rule making, however I am having an issue when setting the 'format' section dynamically.

In the example below, I am looking for the highlighted rule to use the formatting of cell I4 if the square contains 'x' - this way if I change the formatting of I4 to, say, a red background, this rule will automatically update accordingly.

I have had a look and can't seem to find something like the 'format painter' type of thing. Is this at all possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check if this VBA based solution is fine with you. It still internally creates the same Conditional Formatting Rules as required but thru VBA code it now decides the color index based on the color of the cells in I4 and I5.

This example follows the same range as in your question. Range B4:D6 for applying conditional formatting and use reference color from I4 & I5.

In your worksheet say Sheet1 press `ALT + F11`. The VBA Editor will open. Double Click of Sheet1 in left pane and in the right side Code Editor select Worksheet Object (First Drop Down) and then Change Event (Second Drop Down).

Following Subroutine Placeholder shall be available for you therein.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Inside this subroutine place the below VBA Code.

```
'On WorkSheet Change Event Check for Change in C5 and that too if X or O is entered in it.
If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
    If UCase(Target) = UCase(Range("G4").Value) Or UCase(Target) = UCase(Range("G5").Value) Then
        'First clear the Conditional formatting at B4:D6

        Range("B4:D6").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        Range("C5").Select

        'Set the conditional formatting at B4:D6
        Range("B4:D6").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C$5=$G$4"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior

            .Color = Range("I4").Interior.Color

        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        Range("B4:D6").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C$5=$G$5"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior

            .Color = Range("I5").Interior.Color

        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        Range("C5").Select

    End If

End If
```

Save and exit the VBA Editor. Now every time you change value in cell C5 thecode will check if it's C5 and if X or O is entered therein and recreate the conditional formatting rules applies to B4:D6 based on the color from I4 & I5.

You will however need to re-enter value in C5 for this code to work after you modify the background color in I4 and/or I5. VBA Does not offer any Background Color Change event to capture natively. It could however be possible to trap such events using VBA code again though.

[image]

Comment: that you pat2015, however due to limitations I was looking to see if it could be achieved using the in built functions.